# Did the Rashbam write a commentary on the rest of Shas?

Tags: talmud-gemara, rashi, rishonim, tosfot

Rashi's commentary on the Gemara is incomplete on some tractates. The commentary of his grandson, the Rashbam, is printed in its place in [Bava Batra](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=23&daf=29&format=pdf) and [Pesachim](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=4&daf=99b&format=pdf).

Did the Rashbam only write a commentary on those parts of Shas that Rashi had not completed? Or did he write on more tractates, but only those that Rashi hadn't written on were printed? If so, is the rest of his commentary still extant?

<sup><sub>Wikepedia doesn't know about it, but that doesn't count as a source.</sub></sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Encyclopaedia Judaica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encyclopaedia_Judaica) writes (vol. 17 p. 773):

> Only part of his halakhic writings have come down to us. The most significant and important are his supplements to Rashi’s commentary on the Talmud where Rashi did
> not manage to complete his final version. Two of these were published instead of Rashi’s missing commentary – one on chapter 10 of **Pesaḥim,** and the other on most of **Bava Batra,** from folio 29a. [...]
>
> He also wrote *tosafot* to various tractates; only a number of quotations and a greater number of references have been preserved in the standard *tosafot* and in the works of other *rishonim.*
>
> - A larger number of fragments occur in the *tosafot* to the third chapter
>   of **Makkot,** from [folio 20](https://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=25&daf=20b&format=pdf) onward, which are introduced with the words *perush ha-kunteres.* [...]
> - Large sections of his commentary to **Avodah Zarah** have come down in the
>   works of other *rishonim,* when they discuss the themes of this tractate.
> - Many quotations from his commentary to **Avot** are preserved in the anonymous commentary to this tractate in the *Maḥzor Vitry* and in that of *Isaac b. Solomon of Toledo.*

The [Jewish Encyclopaedia](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/13128-samuel-b-meir-rashbam) (cited by the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashbam#Talmudic_works)) also writes about his commentary to **Niddah.**

Comment: JE claims that the Rashbam's commentary to Avodah Zarah is cited in [Temim Deim](https://hebrewbooks.org/1150). If you can help me finding it, I'm happy to edit in a reference.

Comment: Interesting... the Jewish Encyclopaedia is from 1906, which is before they started digging up all the old manuscripts of rishonim. I suppose this is a more recent source. One hopes they [updated it with modern scholarship.](https://seforimblog.com/2007/06/shnayer-leiman-new-encyclopaedia/)

Comment: @H.EugeneWalters EJ obviously incorporates many materials that were simply not available during the time of JE. If you find my answer satisfactory, please [consider accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).